# python xlsxwriter timestamp font incorrect

Tags: python, fonts, timestamp, xlsxwriter

I am writing out from a sqlite DB timestamp info to a column; I set the column font like all the plain text columns. 
This works perfectly. Except where I actually have values in the date column.

```
xlWriter=pd.ExcelWriter(xlPath,engine='xlsxwriter',datetime_format='D-MMM-YY')
```

Gives the correct formatting to the timestamp that I want. 
Because my date format (below, which kinda works); Seems to get overwritten with the default text format (Calibir 11) and the number format is 2019-10-01 00:00:00; where there are values from the timestamp output; the rest of the column has the correct "dateFormat" applied.

```
dateFormat=xlWorkbook.add_format({ 'align': 'right', 'num_format': 'D-MMM-YY', 'font_name':'Arial', 'font_size':'10', 'left':1, 'right':1})


exStr='SELECT  [Date] as "Date [timestamp]",[hours],[travel],[km], [Details] FROM '+tbl
```

All my other columns get the correct formats applied to the entire column e.g.

```
currencyFormat = xlWorkbook.add_format({ 'align': 'right', 'num_format': '$#,##0.00', 'font_name':'Arial', 'font_size':'10','right':1})
detailsFormat=xlWorkbook.add_format({'font_name':'Arial', 'font_size':'8','right':1})
stdFormat=xlWorkbook.add_format({'font_name':'Arial', 'font_size':'10','left':1,'right':1})
```

Comment: Oops....I forgot to actually ask the question...how do I get the timestamp output without overwriting the formatting that I setup.

Answer (score 2):

In XlsxWriter (and Excel) a cell format overrides a column format. Pandas is adding a cell format for each of the datetime cells that it writes to the XlsxWriter file so the column format doesn't have any effect.

I'm not sure how to work around that apart from over-writing all the datetime values with formatted XlsxWriter values, or somehow turning off the Pandas datetime formatting (which I don't think is possible).